# How to "zoom" through multiple levels of Maybe without getting nested Maybes?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

Let's have

```hs
data B = B {_b :: Maybe Int} deriving (Eq, Show, Generic)
makeFieldsNoPrefix ''B

data A = A {_a :: Maybe B} deriving (Eq, Show, Generic)
makeFieldsNoPrefix ''A
```

and now I want to "zoom" onto `b` from `A` (`Maybe Int` in `Maybe B`). I came up with:

```hs
let _TEST :: Maybe Int = (A {_a = Just B{_b = Just 7}}) ^. a ^? _Just . b & join
```

Is it possible to directly get `Maybe Int` using some lens operator without unpacking it with `join` from `Maybe (Maybe Int)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_TEST ^? a . _Just . b . _Just`

Comment: Oh, that was easier than I thought. Thank you.

Comment: For context, `_Just` is a `Prism`, an optic which allows you to focus on part of a sum type, here being used as a `Traversal` that traverses all of the values under the `Just` constructor—all *zero* of them if it’s `Nothing` instead.